# How to reload previews ViewCotroller when user dismisses sheet presentations

Tags: swift, interface-builder, ios13

I am using sheet presentation to view settings view iOS13.when the user dismisses or closes the view I want to trigger reload to previews viewController to update the view.
I tried `viewWillAppear` in previews ViewController but No user 
note even `viewDidLoad`

how to force previews viewController in sheet presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the dismiss function in your settings View Controller and write a delegate to send the reload action.
Assign the delegate to the view controller that you want to send the reload information.

```
protocol MyViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func myViewControllerDidDismiss()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?

    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.delegate?.myViewControllerDidDismiss()
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }

}
```

Other way is making the protocol and overriding viewDidDisappear and send the delegate method when the settings view controller execute the viewDidDisappear. Feel free!